# remote signing with composite templates gets TEMPLATE_NOT_PROVIDED error

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a remote signing envelope that contains a pre defined template and a pdf that i generate on the fly. for that I'm using 2 composite templates joined together as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/master/app/eSignature/examples/eg013_add_doc_to_template/controller.py).
for some reason when trying to send the envelope i get an error from the api:

```
{"errorCode":"TEMPLATE_NOT_PROVIDED","message":"Template was not provided."}
```

although im specifying the template_id in the first CompositeTemplate using ServerTemplate.

here is my python code:

```
 def create_composite_envelope(self, args, return_env=True)):
    """
    Creates and returns an envelope definition
    The envelope request object uses Composite Template to
    include in the envelope:
    1. A template stored on the DocuSign service
    """
    signer1 = Signer(
        email=args['signer_email'],
        name=args['signer_name'],
        role_name="Signer",
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        tabs=args['tabs'],
        # Adding clientUserId transforms the template recipient
        # into an embedded recipient:
        client_user_id=args['signer_client_id']
    )
    # Recipients object:
    recipients_server_template = Recipients(signers=[signer1])

    # 2. create a composite template for the Server template + roles
    comp_template1 = CompositeTemplate(
        composite_template_id="1",
        server_templates=[
            ServerTemplate(sequence="1", template_id=args['template_id'])
        ],
        # Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
        inline_templates=[
            InlineTemplate(sequence="2",
                           recipients=recipients_server_template)
        ]
    )
    if not return_env:
        return comp_template1
    # 3. create the envelope definition with the composited templates
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        status="sent",
        composite_templates=[comp_template1]
    )

    return envelope_definition

 def generate_documents_envelope(self, payload: dict, file_location: str, envelope_id=None):
    # First we create the envelope definition that contains the template
    comp_template1 = self.create_composite_envelope(payload)
    # Now we need to create the envelope that holds the pdf we generated earlier.
    # READING FILES
    with open(path.join(file_location), "rb") as file:
        doc_pdf_bytes = file.read()
    doc_b64 = base64.b64encode(doc_pdf_bytes).decode("ascii")
    # create the DocuSign document object
    document = Document(
        document_base64=doc_b64,
        name="Application Form",  # can be different from actual file name
        file_extension="pdf",  # many different document types are accepted
        document_id="1"  # a label used to reference the doc
    )
    # Create the signer recipient model
    signer1 = Signer(
        email=payload['signer_email'],
        name=payload['signer_name'],
        recipient_id="1",
        routing_order="1",
        role_name="Signer"
    )
    # Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
    # We"re using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
    sign_here1 = SignHere(
        anchor_string="**signature**",
        anchor_units="pixels",
        anchor_y_offset="20",
        anchor_x_offset="10",
        width=130,
        height=40
    )
    full_name = Text(
        anchor_string="**name**",
        anchor_units="pixels",
        anchor_y_offset="0",
        anchor_x_offset="0",
        width=134,
        height=34,
        font="helvetica",
        font_size="size12"
    )

    date = Date(
        anchor_string="**date**",
        anchor_units="pixels",
        anchor_y_offset="10",
        anchor_x_offset="20",
        width=100,
        height=28,
        font="helvetica",
        font_size="size12",
        value=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),
        locked="true"
    )
    # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tabs) to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    signer1.tabs = Tabs(sign_here_tabs=[sign_here1], text_tabs=[full_name], date_tabs=[date])
    recipients = Recipients(signers=[signer1])
    comp_template2 = CompositeTemplate(
        composite_template_id="2",
        inline_templates=[
            InlineTemplate(sequence="1", recipients=recipients)
        ],
        document=document
    )
    # 7. create the envelope definition with the composited templates
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
        status="sent",
        envelope_id=envelope_id,
        composite_templates=[comp_template1, comp_template2]
    )
    return envelope_definition
```

and the final method that creates and sends the envelope definition:

```
  def send_envelope(self, envelope_definition):
    """
    Send the envelope attached
    """
    # Send the envelope
    api_client = ApiClient()
    api_client.host = self.base_path
    api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + self.ds_access_token)
    envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
    results = envelope_api.create_envelope(self.account_id, envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
    return {'envelope_id': results.envelope_id}
```

Comment: random thought - args['template_id'], did you check this has the right value?

Comment: yes double checked. it seems like I'm not injecting the template id in the right place..

Comment: ok I'm getting there.. I realized that i need to return the composite object itself in create_composite_envelope method and not an envelope definition. so now I don't get that error and everything looks fine and don't breaks, except the email is not being sent out.

Comment: is the code above your latest?

Comment: update it just now. you can see the diff in the end of method "create_composite_envelope". the order of functions is 1. generate_documents_envelope. 2. send_envelope

Comment: wow found the final problem!! adding "client_user_id" to Signer Object caused it act like embedded envelope. everything works now.

Comment: That was my guess, but didn't see it in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue - you need to return the composite object itself in **create_composite_envelope** method and not an envelope definition.

Second issue - if you want an email to be sent, don't set the **client_user_id** value which is used for [embedded signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/).